# Windows authentication in IIS 8

Tags: iis, windows-8, ravendb, windows-authentication, iis-8

I am trying to setup RavenDB on my new Windows 8 dev machine. I have enabled Windows Authentication on that particular site and disabled Anonymous Authentication. I am logged in as a Local User account, which is also a member of Administrator. This normally works just fine on my previous Windows 7 dev machine. In this one I keep getting asked for login. I have tried using the account I'm logged in as but I keep getting asked to log in. I'm simply trying to use the RavenDB Studio.

I have tried this on Chrome and IE - probably missing something obvious/fundamental but can't think of what. Any ideas please? Thanks.

Comment: Answered on mailing list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using unstable 1.2 build 2139. It was fixed in build 2140.